# How can I change the .csv file column to something compatible?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, csv, type-conversion

I am trying to get a list of directors and calculate their average score based on all the movies I have in this [.csv file](https://www.kaggle.com/isaactaylorofficial/imdb-10000-most-voted-feature-films-041118). I have written some sample code so it is easier to understand. The sample code works fine but when I'm using the columns from the .csv file it gives me this error, `'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`. Here is the sample code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Director":[ 'Christopher Nolan', 'David Fincher', 'Christopher Nolan', 'Quentin Tarantino', 'Quentin Tarantino', 'Christopher Nolan' ], 
                    "Score": [ 8.9, 9.0, 8.8, 7.8, 9.2, 7.9]})
director_list = []
avg_scores = []
for director in np.unique(df["Director"]):
    director_list.append(director)
    avg_scores.append(df.loc[df["Director"]==director, "Score"].mean())
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Director":director_list, "Score": avg_scores})
df
```

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it :)

This is the code in my main file that is causing the error.

```
data = pd.read_csv('movies.csv') # read in file
dataDirector = data
dataDirector.dropna(subset=['Director', 'Score']) # create data set for year score graph
dataDirector.sort_values(by=['Score'], inplace=True) # order the scores
dataDirector.reset_index()
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Director":dataDirector['Director'], "Score": dataDirector['Score']})
director_list4 = []
avg_scores4 = []

for director in np.unique(df4["Director"]):
    director_list4.append(director)
    avg_scores4.append(df4.loc[df4["Director"]==director, "Score"].mean())
    
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Director":director_list4, "Score": avg_scores4})
df4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it right, that you try to say something like:

```
if score < x: #do something
```

Please check if your x is also a float or integer datatype. As the error says, you probably use a string like "6" instead of an integer or float like 6.

Update:

This statement raises the error:

```
np.unique(df4["Director"])
```

You can't use it for Strings. Try something like

```
df4["Director"].unique()
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't entirely understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Can you post the statement which is raising the error?

Comment: Thanks that works great. I wish I could pick up on things like that.